# Caesar Cipher in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

If I want to write a Caesar cipher C# do I have to go through every case? It doesn't make sense to me to convert to ASCII or UTF (probably because I don't understand how it would work). I just need a point in the right direction.

Should I assign each letter the numbers 1-26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put each letter into an array and use the array index (wrapping at the end) or you could simply use the asccii value of the letter and wrap to the first when reaching the last. The trick here is that all the characters are coninuously sorted, starting at A=0x41

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me, I didn't realise I could do that (I am a complete beginner!).

Answer (score 1):

For a traditional Caesar Cypher, you'd check a char was in the range [a-z] or [A-Z], and just pass it plain otherwise.

An alternative is to treat all characters in the same way, so not only does a become b, but µ becomes ¶ and you wrap around at U+10FFFF (the highest codepoint in Unicode) becomes U+0000 (the former is a non-character and the latter a null character, but there's no reason why a `string` can't hold them to transmit to another place.

In between those two, is to act on the UTF-16. That is, you just add 1 to the value of each `char`, and wrap U+FFFF through to U+0000. The output could become an invalid UTF-16 string (because it could have mis-matched [surrogates](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf#G2630), but that wouldn't prevent you from passing it around in a `string`, and then decyphering it again. After all, modern encryption doesn't result in valid strings either.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, if I want to decode a simple sentence and I convert it to code can I limit the range so that when I want 'z' to be 'b' for example, do I always have to go back and forth can I not make it analogous to a wheel? And thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's a matter of the spec rather than the work (sadly, most real-life complications are like this too, the programming is easier than working out what the client really wants). I'd say the first is *probably* what was intended.
What do you mean by "not analogous to a wheel", any variant of a Caesar cypher is analogous to a wheel.

Comment: I meant wrapping - as I found out from another answer =) - I should have written _can't I make it analogous_. I am still getting used to the terms.

Comment: I was just not getting your wording. The problem with any Q/A is that one can mis-guess which bits the querent already knows perfectly, which bits they don't know, and which bits they are mistaken on, and answer a slightly different question to what they actually want :(

Comment: I understand that, I wasn't very clear there, but your answer still helps me. Anything I can learn from is good, so thank you =D

Comment: Totally. Besides the more wider-ranging answers covering several different cases are more fun to write. I wouldn't bother otherwise ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps dropping hints would be helpful - you say you don't want to copy or be told the answer:

- Consider that C# features the modulus operator, in the form a = b % c - that is, remainder of b divided by c. When c = n and b = n, a = 0. When c = n and b = n+1, a = 1. Experiment with the behaviour of this operator.
- You can declare arrays statically in C# with initialisers: `char[] chars = new char[]{'a', 'b',...};`

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach.

```
    public static string Encrypt(string str, int n)
    {
        return string.Join("", str.Select(x => Encrypt(x, n)));
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string str, int n)
    {
        return string.Join("", str.Select(x => Decrypt(x, n)));
    }

    public static char Encrypt(char chr, int n)
    {
        int x = chr - 65;

        return (char)((65) + ((x + n) % 26));
    }

    public static char Decrypt(char chr, int n)
    {
        int x = chr - 65;

        return (char)((65) + ((x - n) % 26));
    }
```

P.S.

Works only for uppercase letters.

Read the Wikipedia article: [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple class that handles lowercase, uppercase and numbers. It uses the `StringBuilder` class to make the output. To decode a string, you would use the opposite `shift` (if you encrypt with shift = 2, decrypt with shift = -2). I'm also kind of new to C# and come from a C++ background, but I hope this approach works for you or makes it clear how to approach it. I tried commenting so the functionality is clear:

```
class Cypher
{
    static public String CaesarCipher(String input, int shift = 1) {
        if(shift==0) return input;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); //stringbuilder class for ease of use

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) 
        {
            char c = input[i];
            char c2 = c;
            if (((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) || ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) || ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')))  {
                c2 = (char)(c + shift); //make the shift

                if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))  //original char is in this range
                {
                    c2 = CharBindToRange(c2, 'a', 'z'); //clamp the shifted char to range
                }
                else if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z'))
                {
                    c2 = CharBindToRange(c2, 'A', 'Z');
                }
                else if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
                {
                    c2 = CharBindToRange(c2, '0', '9');
                }
            }
            builder.Append(c2); //add the processed character to output
        }
        return builder.ToString(); //return the processed string
    }
    static protected char CharBindToRange(char cinp, char low, char high) //clamps char to specified range
    {
        if (low >= high) { return '?'; }
        if(cinp>high)
        {
            cinp = (char)(low + (cinp - high) - 1);
        }
        else if (cinp < low)
        {
            cinp = (char)(high - (low - cinp) + 1);
        }
        return cinp;
    }
}
```